# SQL function in loop issue

Tags: sql-server, function, while-loop

I have been trying to get this `CURSOR` & `WHILE LOOP` working for about 2 hours now with no luck. I read a few SO threads on this and the [while loop](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178642.aspx) page from Microsoft, perhaps you could let me know what I am doing wrong.

I have a table which looks like this:

```
+-------------------------+-------------------------+
|    Case_CreatedDate     |    Case_UpdatedDate     |
+-------------------------+-------------------------+
| 2013-05-28 12:54:21.250 | 2013-07-02 08:24:02.000 |
| 2010-10-31 19:17:16.000 | 2011-02-02 14:08:04.000 |
| 2010-11-04 11:38:36.000 | 2011-01-18 12:40:15.000 |
| 2011-01-06 16:18:53.000 | 2011-01-06 16:30:25.000 |
| 2011-01-07 10:55:56.000 | 2011-01-14 09:01:40.000 |
| 2011-01-07 11:36:42.000 | 2011-01-13 11:24:03.000 |
| 2011-01-07 12:24:15.000 | 2011-01-17 16:56:41.000 |
| 2011-01-07 14:10:00.000 | 2011-02-14 09:17:55.000 |
| 2011-01-07 14:20:28.000 | 2011-01-14 10:37:20.000 |
| 2011-01-07 14:42:56.000 | 2011-01-14 14:27:41.000 |
| 2011-01-07 15:10:28.000 | 2011-01-21 11:07:50.000 |
| 2011-01-07 15:28:08.000 | 2011-01-26 11:04:27.000 |
| 2011-01-07 15:57:34.000 | 2011-01-20 15:41:43.000 |
| 2011-01-10 08:37:30.000 | 2011-01-14 09:02:43.000 |
| 2011-01-10 08:51:44.000 | 2011-01-13 15:50:26.000 |
| 2011-01-10 08:58:53.000 | 2011-01-26 11:10:54.000 |
| 2011-01-10 09:06:17.000 | 2011-01-14 09:03:33.000 |
| 2011-01-10 09:13:37.000 | 2011-01-19 15:12:07.000 |
| 2011-01-10 09:19:24.000 | 2011-01-26 11:12:37.000 |
| 2011-01-10 09:28:00.000 | 2011-03-08 16:49:59.000 |
+-------------------------+-------------------------+
```

I then have a `function` which calculates the `date difference` between those two dates.

I would like to use this function in conjunction with a while loop and a cursor so it will give me the results of every row when I execute it all.

At the moment, the only result I see is: `"Command(s) completed successfully.
"` - No actual data is displaying to me.

Here is my Current query, could you please let me know where I am going wrong?

```
declare @CreatedDate datetime
declare @UpdatedDate datetime
declare dates CURSOR Local for
    SELECT c.Case_CreatedDate, c.Case_UpdatedDate FROM PILOT.dbo.Cases c 
    WHERE CONVERT(date, c.Case_CreatedDate, 103) >= CONVERT(date, GETDATE(), 103) 


open dates

fetch next from dates into @CreatedDate, @UpdatedDate

while @@FETCH_STATUS = 0 BEGIN

    --Execute my Function
    SELECT dbo.BusinessTurnaroundTime(@CreatedDate, @UpdatedDate)


    fetch next from dates into @CreatedDate, @UpdatedDate
END

close dates
deallocate dates
```

I am using `SQL Server 2008`.

Thanks so much,
Mike

*EDIT: also, dont worry about the dates not being bigger that getdate() the table I am showing you is only the top 20 records.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why are you using a while loop for this my I ask? The same result can be achieved with a simple query:

```
SELECT dbo.BusinessTurnaroundTime(c.Case_CreatedDate, c.Case_UpdatedDate)
FROM PILOT.dbo.Cases c 
WHERE CONVERT(date, c.Case_CreatedDate, 103) >= CONVERT(date, GETDATE(), 103)
```

Thanks.

Comment: Son of a gun! I just Googled how to achieve what i was after and those `cursors` and `while loops` were the 1st things to pop up. Thanks for this, Im going to give it a bash.

Comment: Damn it all to hell... Such a simple solution and I have been over complicating it the ENTIRE morning! Thanks so much for this Nesuke.

Comment: Glad to be of service.

Answer (score 1):

Nesuke gave a much better solution to your problem, just in case you need to work with cursor/while again in the future, here is what was wrong with your query. You dont specify what you want done with your result. You could insert each iteration of the loop into a temp table like this:

```
declare @CreatedDate datetime
declare @UpdatedDate datetime
declare dates CURSOR Local for
    SELECT c.Case_CreatedDate, c.Case_UpdatedDate FROM PILOT.dbo.Cases c 
    WHERE CONVERT(date, c.Case_CreatedDate, 103) >= CONVERT(date, GETDATE(), 103) 
create table #BusinessTurnaroundTime (
    BusinessTurnaroundTime int null)

open dates

fetch next from dates into @CreatedDate, @UpdatedDate

while @@FETCH_STATUS = 0 BEGIN

    --Execute my Function
    insert #BusinessTurnaroundTime 
         dbo.BusinessTurnaroundTime(@CreatedDate, @UpdatedDate)


    fetch next from dates into @CreatedDate, @UpdatedDate
END

close dates
deallocate dates

SELECT * FROM #BusinessTurnaroundTime
```

Comment: Thanks very much for still figuring that out for me +1 :)